# Laravel deployment using Google App Engine: No such file or directory

Tags: google-app-engine

I have followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible) tutorial and created a database under the name `zoho_portal`. My `app.yaml` contents are:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# required on some platforms so ".env" is not skipped
skip_files: false

    env_variables:
      # The values here will override those in ".env". This is useful for
      # production-specific configuration. However, feel free to set these
      # values in ".env" instead if you prefer.
      APP_LOG: errorlog
      STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
      CACHE_DRIVER: database
      SESSION_DRIVER: database
      ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
      DB_HOST: localhost
      DB_DATABASE: zoho_portal
      DB_USERNAME: USER
      DB_PASSWORD: PASS
      DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/zoho-portal-159018:us-central1:zoho-portal 

    beta_settings:
        cloud_sql_instances: "zoho-portal-159018:us-central1:zoho-portal"
```

I have also added this to my `composer.json`:

```
"post-deploy-cmd": [
    "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache"
]
```

However, after deploying this using `gcloud app deploy`, and visiting the website at: https://zoho-portal-159018.appspot.com/, I receive this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from
>   `sessions` where `id` = iq8isoeEqTaj5xVNmVm0JuFKtR8vtSEB0ajJl23o limit
>   1)

As far as I can see, I haven't missed any step listed in the tutorial and the database is set up correctly. Could this have something to do with database migration?

Comment: Visiting your website seems you're receiving SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused error. Please check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615433/app-engine-fails-to-connect-to-google-cloud-sql?answertab=votes#tab-top) to see if it helps.

Comment: I have added `DB_HOST: localhost` in my `app.yaml` file and now I get the `No such file or directory` error, the one with which I have been stuck with for a few weeks. Could you please check and tell what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @AdeelAhmad were you able to resolve the issue? If so it is recommended to post the solution here to better help the community. If not, it is recommended to try the solutions described in the [Google Groups thread here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/IZgep9t3LbI/0AZprAoBBgAJ), along with the reported issue on the [Google PHP Samples Git repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/371).

Answer (score 3):

Your settings are right, so you may have forgotten to [enable](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin) the Cloud SQL Administration API, as it is indicated below "Before you begin" in the [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql).

Comment: I just enabled it (however, I think it was enabled before), but I still get the same `No such file or directory` error. Are you certain this isn't a migration issue?

Comment: The "no such file or directory" error means that the socket file does not exist. In the case of a migration related error it would say something like "schema X not found". Try to connect to the instance via SSH and check what's inside the directory `/cloudsql`. You can also try to remove the `DB_HOST` environment variable, as it is not necessary.

Comment: When I remove the `DB_HOST` environment variable, I get a `Connection refused` error message. Also, where can I find the IP address to establish an SSH connection? I tried the IPv4 address listed in Cloud SQL section, but it always times out.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue but adding `DB_CONNECTION: mysql` to the `env_variables` in my `app.yaml` did the trick for me.